# How do I move or extend something out of the detail panel in MUIx datagrid?

Tags: html, css, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

[image]

I have a line inside a detail panel of a row in MUIx datagrid. But I need to extend the line outside to connect with the plus icon on top. The plus icon on top is part of the detail panel's icon, the bottom two plus icons are my icons inside the detail panel.

I've tried to extend the vertical line using top: -30 in CSS, but it seems like it disappears when it reaches the top of the detail panel which is the bottom of the row. Is there a way I can make it extend outside of the detail panel and reaches the first plus icon?

```
position: absolute;
height: auto;
top: -30px;
width: 1px;
background-color: black;
left: calc(50px / 2);
bottom: 33px;
z-index: 1;
```